# Update a variable reference

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build myself an alternative to requireJS.

So i do something like
`define('Namespace.test.Test').define(function(){ return 'test'})`
Now i need to be able to assign `Namespace.test.Test === 'test'`.

```
var objects = moduleName.split('.'), //moduleName === 'Namespace.test.Test'
    module = Namespace;  
for(var i = 1; i < objects.length; i++) {
    module = module[objects[i]] = module[objects[i]] || {};
}
```

but when i then do `module = defineCallback`it just replaces the module variable and not the `Namespace.test.Test` variable.

A dirty way which i haven't fully figured out would be to do something like this:

```
Namespace[objects[1]][objects[2]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Given that you assigned `module = Namespace`, shouldn't you assign `module.test.Test = defineCallback`?

Comment: @wdosanjos: The op want's to do it dynamically, i.e. create the missing properties in the path string (`Namespace.test.Test`) and assign something to the last property without knowing beforehand what's in the path string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't loop all the way to the last item. Keep one that you can use to access the property:

```
for(var i = 1; i < objects.length - 1; i++) {
  module = module[objects[i]] = module[objects[i]] || {};
}
var name = objects[objects.length - 1];
module[name] = defineCallback();
```

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good idea... no idea why i didn't think of that. Glad i won't have to resort to eval :). Thx